# How I can move vertical line next to the services

Tags: html, css

I want to draw a vertical line next to services heading in the div element, please let me know how I can move vertical line next to the services heading?

HTML part of Code

```
<div class="services">
   <h2>Services</h2>
   <div class="vl">
     <h3>Vertical Line</h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS part of code

```
 .services {
  margin-top: -35px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom:px;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #fcff60;
 }

  .vl {
    border-left: 5px solid rgb(128, 0, 17);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 4em;
    top: 0%;   
  }
```

[image]

Comment: why not apply border directly to heading ? ... why complicating ?

Answer (score 2):

```css
.services {
  margin-top: -35px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom:px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #fcff60;
  }
  
.services h2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px 0 0 ;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.services h2:after {
  border-left: 5px solid rgb(128, 0, 17);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display:block;
}

p{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
    <h2>Services</h2>
    <p>Text next to line</p>
</div>
```

Comment: why a pseudo element ? add the border to the element ... a lot easier

Comment: yes we can use border to element only. If one need to adjust height of vertical line then need to use pseudo element.

Comment: even with border we can adjust the height by using padding

Comment: there are different ways to achieve same things..use one which is suitable for you

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you want your line to be. Just simply add `border-left: 5px solid rgb(128, 0, 17);` to the div `.services`.

Wrap anything you in a `<div></div>` and add a `border` to that wrapping `<div></div>`.

This is the workflow you should follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with CSS alone.
NOTE : You can remove the commented css properties

```
 .services {
   margin-top: -35px;
   /*padding-left: 10px;
   padding-top: 30px;
   padding-bottom:px;*/
     padding:30px 0 0 10px;
   font-size: 40px;
   background-color: #fcff60;
   }
 .services h2{display:inline-block}

   .vl {
     border-left: 5px solid rgb(128, 0, 17);
     /*position: absolute;
     margin-left: 4em;
     top: 0%;*/
     display:inline-block;
 }
```